# Change text in header like a slideshow using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a header on a webpage that is just in a simple h1 tag, and I was wondering if there was a way that you could change the text in this header using a fade effect in a what would be like a looping slideshow, but with text.  I have no idea have I could do this in javascript, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you provide an exemple of what you want to do?

Comment: Basically just an image slider, but with text instead of images

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/1933/)
Do it using the jquery library, it  easier.
Don't forget to include it in your html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```